# Android upside down a layout or rotate by 180

Tags: android, layout, rotation

I am coding an Android game in which 2 players play at the same time. One player faces the phone in a normal way and the other faces it upside down.

As it is a quiz, I didn't use any canvas or graphics. It contains only 2 linear layouts and one of them is supposed to be upside down. For this I have used:

```
android:rotation="180"
```

for one of the layouts.

it showed upside down on the graphical view of my xml in Eclipse but when I run it on an emulator or a phone it is not inverted or rotated to 180 degrees.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:rotation="180">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout
```

**Java Code**

```
public class x extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

How can I rotate it without complication. I am presently using api level 15 but i have no restriction on API level.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a custom Layout that will handle the rotation on it's `onDraw()`

```
public class RotatedLinearLayout extends RotatedLinearLayout {
   final boolean topDown;

   public RotatedLinearLayout (Context context){
   super(context);
   }

   public RotatedLinearLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
   }

   public RotatedLinearLayout (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
      super(context, attrs,defStyle);
   }  


   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
      TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
      textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
      textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

      canvas.save();

      if(topDown){
         canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
         canvas.rotate(180);
      }else {
         canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
         canvas.rotate(-180);
      }
      canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
      getLayout().draw(canvas);
      canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

When you write your XML, use the `VerticalRelativeLayout` instead of the other layout you tried to create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <path.to.package.RotatedLinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:clipToPadding="false"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </path.to.package.RotatedLinearLayout >

</LinearLayout
```

Comment: i dint use any relative layout.

Comment: isnt there a way i can make the linear layout rotate without compilcating things.

Comment: Changed my answer to LinearLayout, try it.